# WCF Rest Service unwanted Retry when throwing WebFaultException

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using a WCF Rest service which is called via JS ajax calls.

For some methods if an exception occurs it is caught and wrapped in a [WebFaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webfaultexception.aspx) which has the status code set to 500 (Internal Server Error) and is thrown.

For the methods that have this behavior we have noticed that the whole call chain that generated an exception at some point is retried for a seemingly random number of times, sometimes it's just once, other times 3, 5, even 7 before the control is passed back to the client side and the error message is shown.

The WebService runs in IIS, and if i hook the debugger to it the retry logic doesn't occur anymore probably because VisualStudio halts the execution due to the unhandled exception.

At first this behavior seem'd to point to [WS-ReliableMessaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480191.aspx) but from the documentation it should be enabled explicitly. Anb we are using a WebHttpBinding, which afaik is not supported.

If I change the Exception behavior to not throw `WebFaultException` then this behavior stops.

Why is this happening?